# Removing ProgressDialog when user presses the back button

Tags: java, android

I have an activity that queries a server database and returns a list of results...while querying the app displays a simple progressDialog on the onCreate method like so:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//display progress dialog while querying server for values
        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,"","Retrieving listings please wait...");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();
```

If the user clicks on an item from the list then another activity placeDetails is opened. Once done a user can press the back button to go back to the previous activity which displays the listings.

When I tested it naturally it shows the above dialog and sends the query back to the server even though the listings can be seen in the background of the progressDialog.

What I want to know is how would I prevent the database being queried again and the above progressDialog from displaying when the user presses the back button.

Do I have to go down the caching route? or is there another way?

Comment: See the Activity lifecycle in the docs. Without elaborating much further you should just cache the data. Use SQLite.

Comment: So that is the only way to do it? Just wanted to confirm that.

Comment: Using persistent storage is the only reliable way, but it's not the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue the missing link was I did not know how to check for dialog windows the following code helped:

```
//first declare the dialog so its accessible globally through out the class
public class ListPlaces extends ListActivity {
 ProgressDialog dialog;
```

then on the onCreate first check that a dialog exists or not

```
if(dialog == null){
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,"","Retrieving listings please wait...");
            //display progress dialog while querying server for values
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.show();
        }
```

And the mistake was I was using

```
dialog.hide();
```

instead of 
    dialog.dismiss();

Thanks for the contributions

Answer (score 0):

1.) To prevent the database from being queried again you can simply cache this data in a local SQLite database as Tom Dignan mentioned.

2.) To prevent the progressDialog from displaying when the user presses the back button, simply override the onBackPressed() method of the current activity (when back is pressed) and set an Intent to the activity that preceeds the progresDialog. I  believe there's even a method to do this so that you won't be starting a new instance of that activity but simply accessing a cached version.